# Regular expression in Javascript for specific expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to create an regex in PHP but I can't; I tried:

```
$sType = preg_replace('/ferm/','fermé', $sType);
```

So I need that after `ferm` to be any character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add `ferm?` to the existing regex.

```
var regExpType = new RegExp("^ouvert|ferm(?:e|\\?)|fermé$","i");
```

Answer (score 0):

If `?` mean any character, you can use this regex:

```
var regExpType = new RegExp("^ouvert|ferm.$","i");
```